# how to manipulate movieclip with nested movieclip inside?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i want to fasten the movie clip playing speed twice time, here's the code

```
mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,function(e:Event):void{
    mc.nextFrame();
});
```

this works if the movie clip only had one level.but with a nested movieclip, it can't help.
when call mc.stop(); the nested movie clip won't stop.i dispatch various event,like enter frame,EXIT FRAME,RENDER to their parent hope make them move to the next frame,but nested movie clip just won't move.

thought there's one way left to get all movieclip object under that movieclip to make them move,but that's not a good choice, since i cant predict what code inside there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function like this:

```
function callOnChildren(container:DisplayObjectContainer, method:String, args:Array = null):void
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < container.numChildren; i++)
    {
        var child:DisplayObject = container.getChildAt(i);
        child[method].apply(child, args);
    }
}
```

And then call `nextFrame()` on all children like so:

```
callOnChildren(mc, "nextFrame");
```

Other methods work too:

```
callOnChildren(mc, "gotoAndStop", [3]);
```

Comment: i had mentioned this is not a good choice.though it can work in some situation.

Comment: hopes there's some way to simulate the enter frame action without really waiting it to call.

Comment: @user2003548 How do you expect to reference children if you don't iterate over them? Even in a typical scenario you would have all the items into some type of list and iterate over them.

Comment: there would be lots of problem if to do this,the nested movieclip might have it own tween animation or it's own code,it's might based on timer or it might stop at some label yet the code would keep them going ,things would got too complicated if i have to handle all those situation.